# mathematics was recreated on a foundation of number concepts rather than geometrical ones

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, analytic-geometry, math-history

In Richard  Courant and Fritz  John's book
 [Introduction  to  Calculus  and  Analysis Volume  I](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=TiWsBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=In%20modern%20times%20mathematics%20was%20recreated%20and%20vastly%20expanded%20on%20a%20foundation%20of%20number%20concepts%20rather%20than%20geometrical%20ones.&source=bl&ots=iXCek0rvpH&sig=OXqSEQTiIfFQn0D3Ga6YVfJEq_I&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY65G_zfzMAhURfiYKHcN1AlsQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=In%20modern%20times%20mathematics%20was%20recreated%20and%20vastly%20expanded%20on%20a%20foundation%20of%20number%20concepts%20rather%20than%20geometrical%20ones.&f=false), says

> In modern times mathematics was recreated and vastly expanded on a
> foundation of number concepts rather than geometrical ones.

Why such recreation happened ? For getting rid of the limitations of geometrical methods ?

Comment: Because you can't construct some numbers with geometry but you need them those numbers for  various reason. Eg $\pi$, $e$.

Comment: @ritwiksinha I'd say we can "construct" or define $\;\pi\;$ with geometry: it is simply the ratio of any circle's perimeter to twice its radius. Did you have perhaps some other meaning of "construction" in mind?

Comment: Could you please add at least the title and author of the book to the body of your question?

Comment: Algebra: the development of algebra (folowing arabic sources) during the Renaissance and Scientific Revolution produced tools for "symbolic manipulation" much more flexible and powerful that ancient Greek "geometrical" techniques of proof.

Comment: For the purpose of calculus, this is a reasonable statement, but once you take more advanced math classes, you realize that in modern times the most fundamental concept is that of a set,  not of a number.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Added, but  why I should add them ?

Comment: @Joanpemo: Perhaps the "construction" refers to construction using Euclidean tools (ruler and compass). If $x$ is a positive real number then it is not difficult to prove that starting from a line segment of unit length it is possible to construct a line segment of length $x$ by using ruler and compass if and only if $x$ can be expressed as a finite combinations of rational numbers together with operations $+,-,\times,/,\sqrt{}$.

Comment: @iMath: Thank you. :) In general it's a good idea to make questions as self-contained as is feasible, since web links break over time. Separately, I (for one) wasn't going to click a google books link to find the source of the quote.

Comment: This would also be a good fit for [hsm.se]

Comment: @Joanpemo If i tell you to draw a line of length $\pi$, can you do it ?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you, I know.

Comment: @ritwiksinha Using what? Using the basic tools defined in times of the greeks I can draw a circle, so $\pi\;$ is just the ratio I mentioned before. Of course, we now know we can't *construct* $\;\pi\;$ as the greeks defined "construction" and only with a ruler and a compass, as it is a transcendental number, yet "construction" could have several meanings.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes i mean a ruler and a compass.

Comment: @Joanpemo sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should provide further context for that quote, e.g. quote the entire paragraph, else you will probably get answers unrelated to the author's intent.

Comment: @BillDubuque For  further context for that quote, click the link to find more.

Comment: @iMath The point of my prior comment is that many readers *won't* folllow the link, so they may misinterpret the (very specific) context of the remark - which is essential to understand to properly answer the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque Tanks for your kind tips, will have it in mind next time .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you recommend some reading materials on what you said ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Proofs using geometrical intuition and Euclid axioms were almost the norm in ancient Greek mathematics. However side by side the idea of numbers was also developing for obvious practical needs (i.e. counting and measuring). With advent of algebra it became obvious that *methods based on algebraic manipulation of numbers were far more powerful than the non-obvious geometrical arguments based on Euclidean axioms* and this was the main reason for shift of focus from geometry to arithmetic/algebra.

Use of algebra became so much so prevalent that it became fashionable to study geometry using numbers (co-ordinate geometry). However as many mathematicians during 1800-1900 realized the idea of replacing geometrical concepts with numbers was not easy. The concept of *a straight line as a smooth continuum of points* was very difficult to map with the existing theory of numbers (which basically was a theory of numbers accessible via algebraic techniques i.e. the numbers considered were algebraic). Only with the development of a proper theory of real numbers by Cantor, Dedekind, Weierstrass it was possible to map the points of a line with real numbers and the set of real numbers could then be viewed as a sort of *arithmetical continuum*.

---

All this development by the way had a side effect. The charm of Euclid's Elements is no more available in standard high school curriculum. Only the bare minimum material based on Euclid axioms is covered in school syllabus and students get to learn analytic geometry and tools of calculus to deal with general curves. The beautiful theory of conics by Apollonius of Perga is a remarkable work based on Euclid axioms and sadly very few students are aware of it. I did study some of it from the book *Apollonius, Treatise on Conic Sections* by T. L. Heath and wrote [some posts](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/06/conics-and-the-cone-part-1.html) on conics.

Comment: +1 for the side effects. I think both methodologies should be taught.
because i think, euclidean geometry is much more beautiful than analytical geometry with calculus.

Comment: agree with your views @ritwiksinha

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Great ! you helped me again ! Where have you learned these history of math?

Comment: @iMath: check my profile on MSE. After school years (meaning till age 17) I studied most of the stuff online.

Comment: Well, Excellent!!!

Comment: I agree with methods based on algebraic manipulation of numbers were far more powerful than the non-obvious geometrical arguments. Besides, I think showing mathematical concept through geometrical method is obvious and easy to understand , but there may exist cases where unexpected or counterintuitive things happens out of our sight because of our carelessness when using geometrical method ,

Comment: so introduction to math concept by geometric intuition can make no claim to being scientific, while on the other hand, methods based on algebraic manipulation is often more thorough than the geometrical ones so that use of algebra became more prevalent than geometrical methods , all right ?

Comment: @iMath: I more or less agree with both the comments. However note that geometry as based on axioms of Euclid is a genuine subject full of rigor. Unfortunately most people don't have much experience with arguments using Euclidean axioms and instead try to think by looking at geometrical figures drawn on a sheet of paper. Thus for example a point/line/circle is an abstract geometrical concept and its drawing on a paper only approximately resembles the abstract concept.

Comment: @iMath: Moreover Euclidean axioms are difficult to apply for complicated curves unless you combine them with the analytical approach (coordinate geometry + calculus).

Comment: Thanks for reply, In the preface of Dedekind's Essays on the Theory of Numbers http://imgur.com/wRwPqL0 says introduction into the differential calculus by geometric evidences can make no claim to being scientific, so what is the reason ?

Comment: @iMath: I think Dedekind wants to emphasize the geometric intuition can not be trusted when we are dealing with complicated curves (for example curve which is continuous everywhere but does not possess tangent at every point). Dedekind was one of the first mathematicians who realized that it was necessary to ditch dependency on calculus on geometric intuition and he felt the need to introduce real numbers not as points on a number line, but as some objects made out of rationals (like rationals are something made using ratio of integers).

Comment: @iMath: And this led to the birth of the elegant theory of real numbers as Dedekind cuts of rational numbers. You must read Dedekind's pamphlet "Continuity and Irrational Numbers" in this regard.

Comment: Thanks very much , yes, I am reading this pamphlet http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/courses/math140/dedekind-book.pdf

Comment: Hello, @ParamanandSingh please read [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2518245/34603)   at your convenient, it is about my research on Dedekind's construction of the number continuum, looking forward to your reply:)